# Terse syntax to return an empty result set from SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, sql-server-2014, derived-table

Is there a shorter way to write the following?

```
-- select empty_result
select t.col
from (select 1 as col) t
where 1 = 0 -- never match
```

---

The "original" question follows. This was was modified may times, explicitly in hopes of stopping Y responses as a result of showing a specific use-case; and [rightly] claimed to be a confusing mess.

The use-case is a TSQL query that returns an empty result set in some cases while a 'real' result set in another. In both cases the structure is expected to be the same.

```
 if @foo = 'bar'
   -- select real_result
 else
   -- select empty_result
```

The question here is then, *specifically* about creating an empty result set / derived table simply.

One way to do this is as follows. Is there a *syntactically 'simpler'* method?

```
-- select empty_result
select t.col
from (select 1 as col) t
where 1 = 0 -- never match
```

---

An alternative in this specific MINIMAL `IF..ELSE..` CASE, it *could* be constructed as the following SQL. It is (XY) outside the question scope even though it would function here as the resulting schema is the same in the example above. While it may be a good option *elsewhere*, it requires a different TSQL flow-control structure. It will also not return the correct result sets if both cases result in a different schema - making it too specific in respect to the title scope.

```
-- XY alternative specific to MINIMAL CASE shown above
-- select real_result or empty_result with single query
select t.col
from real_data t
where @foo = 'bar'
```

Comment: `select t.col from real_data t where 1 = 0` seems to work.

Comment: `where @foo = 'bar'` also works @Ken White.

Comment: I didn't get it well, what's the problem with `where @foo = 'bar'` or `if @foo = 'bar'`? What're you really asking for?

Comment: @Sami: Yes, I know. The OP seems to be looking for alternatives to using that for some reason.

Comment: @Sami @KenWhite The XY was _explicitly included_ for the `where @foo = 'bar'` case to avoid a digression into it (as it changes the structure of the TSQL and flow-control). Although using the select `from real_data where 1 = 0` inside the negative-case is something not considered .. and I do like it better here as then the schema is not doubled-up.

Comment: in place of null = null try to use null is null

Comment: @user3510665 Then it _would_ match. Using `1 = 0` would be more clear that it should not match (as `null = null` looks like a typo..). I've update the question to make this more explict.

Comment: @user2864740 `1=0` will always returns an empty result-set. While `@foo = 'bar'` will returns all the rows if the condition evaluated to `True`. Your Q as it is makes no sense for me tbh.

Comment: See the title for why an empty-result is correct (and thus the no-match condition). See why this is important in relationship to the flow-control IF. Both the IF form and the non-IF forms are expected to be _equivalent_ in result set. One uses a TSQL conditional branch, the other does not.

Comment: What is your question here? Is it basically "which is best out of a single statement approach or two statements and IF"?

Comment: From the body: "The question here is then, _specifically_ about creating an empty result set / derived table simply. One way to do this is as follows. Is there a 'simpler' method?" (Where using the primary table was explicitly excluded in scope.)

Comment: _IFF_ the question was about IF vs non-IF, there would not have been so much wording mentioning such, and then excluding such ("It is (XY) outside the question [.. and] while [using a filter on the original table] may be a good option _elsewhere_, it requires a different TSQL flow-control structure."). A 'simpler' approach to creating an empty derived table might be something like `select top 0 1 foo` (*shrug*). Instead, so many people are interested in Y. I'm not.

Comment: @MartinSmith This question is also explicitly tagged with 'syntax'. I added that to the question body as well _just so it can also be ignored_. The title has also been updated for those who appear to stop reading there. Geeze.

Comment: The state of the question when I read it was just a confusing mess frankly. Looking at the edit history it appears you have incorporated elements from comments making it unclear what the actual question is

Comment: @MartinSmith Fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a 'simpler' / shorter / more terse syntax to returning an empty result set in SQL Server that does not require first creating a derived table.

```
-- select empty_result
select top 0
  1 as col
```

This is SQL Server specific syntax. There might be other similar forms found in other database implementations.

---

While not specifically about a shorter empty result set syntax, Ken White provided an approach which avoids duplicating schema if it's identical in both cases. The IF flow-control structure is *preserved*, as per the original question.

```
if @foo = 'bar'
  -- select real_result
  select t.col
  from real_table t
else
  -- select empty_result
  select t.col
  from real_table t
  where 1 = 0
```